# Proof $\int\limits_{-1}^1f(x)dx=2\int\limits^1_0f(x)dx$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$

Tags: integration, analysis, functions

Let $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is even, i.e. it holds that $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$

How can one prove that f is integrable over $[-1,1]$ so that the following holds?

$$\int\limits_{-1}^1f(x)dx=2\int\limits^1_0f(x)dx$$

For example $f(x) = x^4 + 3x^2-1$ is symmetrical because $f(-x) = x^4 + 3x^2 - 1$. The integral would then be $0.4$ in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write
$$ \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \,\mathrm dx = \int_{0}^1 f(x) \,\mathrm dx + \int_{-1}^0 f(x) \,\mathrm dx $$
and substitute $x\mapsto -x$ in the second integral.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using the fundamental theorem of calculus:

Let $\phi(t) = \int_{-t}^t f(x)dx - 2 \int_0^t f(x)dx$. Then $\phi(0) = 0$ and $\phi'(t) = f(t)-f(-t)- 2 f(t) = 0$, and so
$\phi(t) = 0$.